# Java swing: How do i detect if the key pressed will display output in my JTextArea?

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, keyevent

I'm working on a text editor, and I want to be able to detect the difference between two distinct types of key events: the ones that result in a visible change to the text in my JTextArea (ie, alphanumeric characters, the enter key, symbols), and the ones that don't result in a visible change (directional keys, control keys, shortcuts). I know I can do this with a very verbose switch statement, but is there a less verbose way to do the following?

```
private void checkKey (java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
    if (saved && /*some way to check if the text in the box has changed */) {
        editorTitle.setText(currentedit + " (Edited)");
        saved = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use a KeyListener. There are better API's to handle these situation.

If you want to know if the data in the text component has changed then you should be using a `DocumentListener`. It will generate an event whenever text is added or removed.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Write a DocumentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) for more information.

If you want to know when an arrow key is pressed to invoke some kind of Action then you should be using `Key Bindings`. This is how all Swing components work. A `KeyStroke` is bound to an `Action`.

See [Key Bindings](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/key-bindings/) for more information and a complete list of the default key bindings of each component.

Shortcuts are also implemented in Swing by using Key Bindings.